# When would a left admissible triangulated subcategory be admissible

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories, adjoint-functors

I'm walking through the proof of [1, Thm 16 at pp. 515] and am stuck at the first sentence after equation (12), where the author states that the decomposition (12) is semiorthogonal when $a\geq 0$. What I can't see is why the terms of the decomposition (12) are admissible.

As you can see it's quite involved so I'll ask an easy-to-state question instead that is sufficient to solve my problem. If my claim turns out to be false, I would try my best to explain the notations and lemmas that are required to state the problem.

**Question**: Let $\cal A$ be a triangulated category, and $\cal B$ be a right admissible subcategory, which means that $\cal B$ is a triangulated subcategory and the inclusion functor has a right adjoint. Assume further that $\cal B$ and $\cal B^\perp$ are mutually orthogonal, i.e. $\text{Hom}({\cal B}^\perp, {\cal B})=0$. Would it imply that $\cal B$ is also left admissible?

[1] *Orlov, Dmitri*, [**Derived categories of coherent sheaves and triangulated categories of singularities**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4747-6_16), Tschinkel, Yuri (ed.) et al., Algebra, arithmetic, and geometry. In honor of Y. I. Manin on the occasion of his 70th birthday. Vol. II. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-0-8176-4746-9/hbk; 978-0-8176-4747-6/ebook). Progress in Mathematics 270, 503-531 (2009). [ZBL1200.18007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1200.18007).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. The left adjoint to the corresponding embedding is simultaneously a right adjoint. Just note that $A\cong B\bigoplus B^{\perp}$.